# Camel route to connect two databases

Tags: apache-camel, integration

I have a requirement to bring data from two different databases. From the first database (PostGres) I have to fetch a last run date based on a periodic schedule, say daily. Then I need to connect to the second database (Oracle) and bring all the new records updated after the last run date for processing. At the end, I need to update the Last run date in the first database. I need some help in writing the Camel route. I am thinking to use a scheduler which will poll the first DB for last run date. Later I will fetch the details from second database using a poll enrich. Wanted to know if my thinking is right from Camel route perspective or is there a simpler, better way. Greatly appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find a solution. i also had a similar requirement and had to update multiple database .

Comment: I thought of using PollEnrich / Enrich. But later I believe a simpler soultion would be to use a bean and make the different calls using COnsumerTemplate